# Matlab - Concatenate multidimensional matrix row elements and output single row matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

I'm trying to manipulate some data in Matlab that I'm having trouble with.

I have a matrix that looks like this.

```
[c, a, b, a]
|a, b, c, d|
|a, c, d, b|
|b, a, c, d|
[d, a, b, c]
```

and I would like to concatenate each row into a single string element and put those into a single row matrix.

Like this:

```
[caba,abcd, acdb, bacd, dabc]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I can only thinking of using `cell` for a solution like `data = {['c','a','b','a'];['a','b','c','d'];['a','c','d','b'];['b','a','c','d'];['d','a','b','c']}'`

Comment: Can you provide further insight on how this matrix is structured?  Is each element a single character?  Would this be a character array?  If it is, then each row is already considered a single string already.  Can you provide the actual code you used to construct this matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initial_char_matrix=['c','a', 'b', 'a';
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd';
'a', 'c', 'd', 'b';
'b', 'a', 'c', 'd';
'd', 'a', 'b', 'c']


cell_a=cell(1,size(initial_char_matrix,1));

for i=1:size(initial_char_matrix,1)
   stringjoined=''; 
    for j=1:size(initial_char_matrix,2)
      stringjoined= strcat( stringjoined,initial_char_matrix(i,j));
    end
    cell_a{i}= stringjoined;
end
```

Output:

```
>> celldisp(cell_a)

cell_a{1} =

caba


cell_a{2} =

abcd


cell_a{3} =

acdb


cell_a{4} =

bacd


cell_a{5} =

dabc

>>
```

You can use this strings as

```
cell_a{index}
```